# Add back button to GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using google's drive api and in their starter code they have this line:

```
let login = createAuthController()
present(login, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This creates a view controller with no back button like so: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTl0n.jpg

How do i add a back button to this view? i tried login.addsubview(button) but that doesnt work